# Deciding whether $f^{-1} (f(A)) = A$ or $f(f^{-1}(B)) = B$

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

$X$ and $Y$ are two sets and $f:X\to Y$. If $f(C)=\{f(x):x\in C\}$ for $C\subseteq X$ and $f^{-1}(D)=\{x:f(x)\in D\}$ for $D\subseteq Y$, then the true statement is

(A) $f(f^{-1}(B))=B$

(B) $f^{-1}(f(A))=A$

(C) $f(f^{-1}(B))=B$ only if $B\subseteq f(X)$

(D) $f^{-1}(f(A))=A$ only if $f(X)=Y$

Comment: What is(are) the difference(s) between the pairs of statements 1. (A) and (C) and 2. (B) and (D)?

Comment: $\{f(c)=y; c\in X; c\subset X,y\subset Y\}$ and $\{f^{-1}(d)=x;d\subset Y,x\subset X\}$ are not statements. They are unintelligible. So I cannot tell what the Q is.

Comment: @JoshuaHunt I know where this question is taken from. I have edited the question.

Comment: @Aditya Dev. What do (C) and (D) mean? For some (all) $b\subset y\subset Y$?(Etc.)

Comment: I dont understand you @user254665

Comment: So $f(c) = \{y; c \subset X, y \subset Y\}$ still doesn't make any sense @AdityaDev ! Could you explain what you mean by that? (In words, if necessary)

Comment: @JoshuaHunt I dont know what to do. This question is from an entrance exam paper. I tried checkinh this question in some books. Each book has thier own version of the question. I can attach photos if you want. One book has replaced $\subset$ with $\in$.

Comment: @JoshuaHunt the edited question is from a different book.

Comment: @user202729 typo.

Comment: @AdityaDev What is the relationship between $c$ and $C$? If they are one, means f take both "subset of X" and "element of X" as input?

Comment: @user202729 they are different.

Comment: @AdityaDev $f$ must be injective since $f^{-1}$ is defined, but is it bijective?

Maybe you means $f(c) \in \{f(x):x\in C\}$ ($\in$, not $=$)?

What do you means by $f(X)=Y$ when X and Y are domain and codomain respectively?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/39050/discussion-between-aditya-dev-and-user202729).

Comment: @AdityaDev  Do you agree to the edit made by Alex M?  .

Comment: @Ramiro: He must agree with me :), otherwise his problem wouldn't make sense.

Comment: @AlexM. The point is that AdityaDev (the person who set the bounty) explictly insisted that the lowercase and uppercase letters (such as $c$ and $C$) meant different things. See comments above.

Comment: @Ramiro: I know, I've read them. This shows that neither the OP, nor the bounty giver has understood the question. This should worry them, given that it is from an entrance exam paper. There is also the possibility that the question has been misprinted in the book where it has been copied from, in which case it makes sense for the OP and the bounty giver to be confused. In any case, I stand by my corrections and my answer - and I'm adamant about it!

Comment: @AlexM.I agree with you that the question was very strange, and it were reasonable to change it, as you did. However, you were not the first smart guy to notice it. People before you (including me) had the same perception, and AdityaDev, who set the bounty, explicitly said the question was meant to be in that strange way, which stopped people from editing the question. 
Let us wait to see what AdityaDev says about your editing.

Comment: @AlexM. AdityaDev post 2 images in the chat, one of them avoid this typo (this version replace C by A, so this edit is completely correct.

Answer (score 3):

Let $X = \Bbb R, \ Y = [0, \infty)$ and $f(x) = x^2$. If $A = (-\infty, 0]$, then $f(A) = [0, \infty)$ and $f^{-1} (f(A)) = f^{-1} ([0, \infty)) = \Bbb R \ne A$, therefore $f^{-1} (f(A)) \ne A$, so (B) is false.

Let $X = [0, \infty), \ Y = \Bbb R$ and $f(x) = x$. If $A \subseteq X$, then $f(A) = A \subseteq Y$, so $f^{-1} (f(A)) = f^{-1} (A) = A$. Nevertheless, $f(X) \ne Y$, so (D) is false.

Let $X = \Bbb R, \ Y = \Bbb R$ and $f(x) = x^2$. Let $B = [-1,1]$. Notice that $f^{-1} (B) = f^{-1} ([0,1]) = [-1, 1]$ (because $f^{-1} ([-1,0)) = \emptyset$), so that $f (f^{-1} (B)) = f([-1,1]) = [0,1] \ne B$, therefore (A) is false, too.

Finally, let us investigate (C).

Let $B \subseteq f(X)$. If $y \in B \subseteq f(X)$, then there exist $x \in X$ such that $f(x) = y \in B$, so $x \in f^{-1} (B)$, which implies (just apply $f$) that $f(x) \in f(f^{-1}(B))$, so $y \in f(f^{-1} (B))$. This shows that $B \subseteq f(f^{-1} (B))$. For the opposite inclusion, if $y \in f(f^{-1} (B))$, then there exist $x \in f^{-1} (B)$ with $y = f(x)$; but $x \in f^{-1} (B)$ means that $f(x) \in B$ (this is what "inverse image" means), so then $y = f(x) \in B$. We have thus proved that $f(f^{-1} (B)) \subseteq B$. Since we have inclusions in both directions, we have proved that $B \subseteq f(X) \implies B = f(f^{-1} (B))$.

Assume now that $B = f(f^{-1} (B))$ and let $C = B \cap f(X), \ D = B \setminus f(X)$; notice that $B = C \cup D$, $C \cap D = \emptyset$ and $f^{-1} (D) = \emptyset$. Then $$B = f(f^{-1} (B)) = f(f^{-1} (C \cup D)) = f(f^{-1} (C) \cup f^{-1} (D)) = f(f^{-1} (C)) \cup f(\emptyset) = f(f^{-1} (C)) .$$ Since $D \subseteq B = f(f^{-1} (C)) \subseteq f(X)$, we deduce that $D = \emptyset$, so $B \subseteq f(X)$. We have thus proved that $B = f(f^{-1} (B)) \implies B \subseteq f(X)$.

To conclude, not only is (C) the only true statement, it is true in a much stronger form, with logical equivalence instead of just implication.

Comment: This is how I solved the question and thought that option (C) was correct. I assumed the function $f(x)=x^2$. But the answer given in the books were contradicting. (D) was given as the correct answer in most of the books. I just wanted to check my answer. Thats why I brought this question back to life :)

Answer (score 2):

`(A) is not true`.
Let $X=A=\{a\}$, and $Y=B=\{a,b\}$. Define $f:X\to Y; \quad f(a)=a.$ Then $f(f^{-1}(B))=\{a\}\neq B.$

---

`(B) is not true`.
Let $X=Y=\{a,b\}$, and $A=B=\{a\}$ . Define $f:X\to Y; \quad f(x)=a, \forall x\in X.$ Then $f^{-1}(f(A))=X\neq A.$

---

`(D) is not true`.
Let $X=\{a,b\}$, $Y=\{a,b,c\}$, and $A=B=\{a\}$. Define $$f:X\to Y; \quad f(x)=x, \forall x\in X.$$
We have $f^{-1}(f(A))=A,$ but $f(X)\neq Y.$

---

`(C) is true`:
Let $f(f^{-1}(B))=B.$  We should prove $B\subseteq f(X).$ If not, we have $b\in B\setminus f(X).$ Hence $b\in B\setminus f(f^{-1}(B)),$ Since $f^{-1}(B)\subseteq X.$ (contradiction!)